# Non-Standard Syntax Error in Thread Constructor

Tags: c++

I'm currently looking at producing a C++ library. I've not much experience with C++ and have what is probably a very basic question about class instance method calling.

## main.cpp

```cpp
msgserver m;
std::thread t1(m.startServer, "192.168.50.128", 8081);
```

## msgserver.h

```cpp
class msgserver
{
public:    
    msgserver() { }
    int startServer(std::string addr, int port);
};
```

## msgserver.cpp

```cpp
int msgserver::startServer(string addr, int port)
```

This code results in:

```
[C3867] 'msgserver::startServer': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

I know i can fix the compiler error by making this method static but I'm unsure if that is a requirement imposed by the fact it's being called in a thread constructor (which doesn't allow the parens on the call signature) or if I need to figure out the syntax.

I've read around this and it's actually left me a bit more confused that when I started. It seems any fix I apply like:

```cpp
int &msgserver::startServer(string addr, int port)
or
std::thread t1(&m.startServer, "192.168.50.128", 8081);
```

Is actually illegal syntax according to the compiler.

How can I call this as an instance method? Or is actually a good idea to start a thread running in the background on a static function?

Comment: I'm not using any textbook. I'm guessing you're going to tell me that's my first mistake ... ;)

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: `std::thread t1(&msgserver::startServer, m, "<ip>", 8081);`

Comment: I'm well aware, it's why I've only skirted around C++ until now where it's pretty much required. I've got 25 years desktop dev behind me in other languages which helps.

Comment: @Jammer *I've got 25 years desktop dev behind me in other languages which helps* -- One huge warning -- do **not** use any of those languages as a model in writing C++ code.  If you use any of those languages as a model, you will wind up with 1) Buggy code, 2) Inefficient code, 3) Code that looks weird to a C++ programmer when trying to make C++ look like language <X>'s way of doing things.  C++ has to be learned as if none of those other languages exist.  For 3), I've seen `int y = 10; string x = "" + y;`, which looks ordinary to a Java programmer, but is totally wrong in C++ (concatenating).

Comment: I'm under no illusions, believe me. I've listened to enough interviews with Bjarne to know that if the guy that invented it says he doesn't get some of it there's little hope for a mere mortal like me. BUT everyone started somewhere. Right?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that said, every can publish books, too. Find good source, regardless it's form (although it's always hard for beginner).

Comment: I'm also eyeing up Rust as I can produce a binary compatible dll with that language as well.

Comment: Also, I'm starting with something I need and is really a very tiny project. I've always found those two things make for a good basis for learning. Even if the expression in C++ isn't simple, the goal is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `int y = 10; string x = "" + y;` that's just hideous in any language.

Comment: @Jammer -- I know, but was surprised that doing this was a "thing" in Java programs.

Comment: I get horrified by the stuff I see in JavaScript too. Hideous spaghetti. I avoid java but that looks like java auto converts the int to a string. Even if you could do it, why? Readability is 0/10.

Comment: @Jammer That's exactly what it does.  You would be surprised how many Java programmers just do this, because that's what they're used to seeing.  Now imagine a Java programmer trying to concatenate an `int` onto a string in C++, and they write that code.  Then they can't understand why their C++ code doesn't work.  But a C++ programmer looking at that same code would see it looks totally alien, weird, and just plain nuts.  That is the perfect example of using another language as a model in writing C++ code, and totally failing.

Comment: I've always stuck to and prefer typed languages. Day job is mostly C#. That code wouldn't even compile in C#, quite rightly too. I could make something the same but nah! No way. I do C a bit as well. for electronics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for a getting a pointer to a member function is `&<class name>::<function_name>`.

In this case `&msgserver::startServer` would be the correct expression. Since `std::invoke` is used on the background thread, you need to pass the object to call the function for as second constructor parameter for `std::thread`, either wrapped in a `std::reference_wrapper` or by passing a pointer:

```
std::thread t1(&msgserver::startServer, std::ref(m), "192.168.50.128", 8081);
```

or

```
std::thread t1(&msgserver::startServer, &m, "192.168.50.128", 8081);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
msgserver m;
std::thread t1(m.startServer, "192.168.50.128", 8081);
```

with the *lambda function*

```
msgserver m;
std::thread t1([=](std::string addr, int port){ m.startServer(addr, port); }, 
    "192.168.50.128", 8081);
```

I'm guess that you expected your version to do what the lambda function does by some kind of C++ magic. But that's not how C++ works.

Completely endorse the recommendation that you get a C++ book. Now you have lambda functions to add to your list of topics to learn.

Comment: Ahhhh lambdas. Thank you. Will go study and test.

Comment: Missing a closing "}"

Comment: @Jammer Yes, fixed now

Comment: Ahhh, fixed. Fab. Thank you, will go check.

Comment: @Jammer Also missing semi colon

Comment: @Jammer This lambda function copies the msgserver object, that may or may not be a good idea. If not then replace `[=]` with `[&]` but then you have the new issue that the lifetime of your thread and the lifetime of your msgserver are no longer linked.

Comment: no need to use a lamda to invoke a member function of an object with a thread, `std::thread` can do that for you